# I am getting an unpacking error in matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to generate an animated graph for my school project . First, I made a still representation of the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), but my teacher told me to animate the graph:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
a=int(input('Enter the desired number:'))
for n in range(a):
    i=n
    l=[n]
    x=[]
    def animation_function(i):
        while i>1:
            if i%2==0:
                i=int(i/2)
            else:
                i=int(3*i+1)
            l.append(i)
        j=0
        while j<len(l):
            x.append(j+1)
            j+=1
        #plt.plot(x,l)
    figure, ax=plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xlim(0,len(x))
    ax.set_ylim(0,max(l))
    line, ax=plt.subplots()
    line, animation=FuncAnimation(figure,
                          func = animation_function,
                          frames = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1), 
                          interval = 10)   
    
plt.show()
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\SPARSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\3x+1.2.py", line 23
    ax.set_xlim(0,len(x))
UserWarning: Attempting to set identical left == right == 0 results in singular transformations; automatically expanding.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\SPARSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\3x+1.2.py", line 24
    ax.set_ylim(0,max(l))
UserWarning: Attempting to set identical bottom == top == 0 results in singular transformations; automatically expanding.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SPARSH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\3x+1.2.py", line 26, in <module>
    line, animation=FuncAnimation(figure,
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable FuncAnimation object
```

I am new to matplotlib, so please tell me if I missed something small and stupid or did a huge mistake.

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html#animation) what the general structure of FuncAnimation calls is. It is also not clear what exactly the animation is supposed to show.

Comment: It is supposedd to show the nature of any number in colatz conjucture

Comment: I know you mentioned this but what is the animation supposed to show after the integer `a` has been provided? Seemingly, some lineplot will be generated for all integers in the range of 0 to `a` but what does this line represent and how does it change with each iteration? This is probably clear to you because you know what you want to show - but not to us.

Comment: a is basically the limit of how many line graphs will be there

Comment: suppose if we take a as 9 so first number after 0 and 1 will be 2 for n so if 2 is even then it is halved so 1, then the loop for n stopped , next iteration is for 3 it is odd so number id=s of the form 3x+1 so 3*3+1 i.e. 10 and then 10 is even so it is halved i.e. 5 and then it is odd so again the number is 3*5+1 and so on until it reaches 1

Comment: I understand the principle of the conjecture. The question is how do you want to animate these changes for each numbers `2...a`? Maybe it should be a lineplot (1, 9) - (2, 28) - (3, 14) - (4, 7) -....- (k, 1) and this for each number`2...a`? Maybe a directed graph showing how all numbers converge? Maybe something else? Should one number after the other be animated, all together, each in its own subplot? How do you imagine your animation?

Comment: yeah the lineplot should be (1,9),(2,28),(3,14)....(k,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the lines have different lengths, I would refrain from using FuncAnimation and instead use the interactive plotting with [`plt.ion()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/interactive.html?highlight=interactive). I tried to mainly keep your structure, but introduced some changes.
First, I got rid of the x-range lists. This is implicit information of your list `l`, so we don't have to collect it separately.
Second, as the graph does not auto-update when plotting outside values, we have to collect the maximum values for the x and y axes, so we know when we have to update the graph limits.
Finally, we plot each line object once, then update its values in each new iteration. An implementation could then look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

respon = "Y"
plt.ion()

while respon == "Y":
    a=int(input('Enter the desired number:'))
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    xmax = 1
    ymax = 1
        
    for n in range(1, a+1):
        i=n
        l=[n]
         
        line, = ax.plot([1, 1], [i, i],  marker="o", label = str(i))
        ax.legend() 

        while i>1:
            if i%2==0:
                i=int(i/2)
            else:
                i=int(3*i+1)
            l.append(i)
            line.set_ydata(l)
            line.set_xdata(range(1, 1+len(l)))
            
            ymax = max(ymax, i)
            xmax = max(xmax, 1+len(l))
            
            ax.set_xlim(0.5, xmax+0.5)
            ax.set_ylim(0.5, ymax+0.5)

            plt.pause(0.5)    
   
    respon = input("repeat? Y/n")
    plt.close()

print("finished")
```

Sample output:
[image]